# Cannot use Maps JavaScript API on vue (nuxt)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

here is code that i try

```
head: {
        script: [
            {
                src: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete",
            },
        ],
    },


mounted() {
        new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            document.getElementById('autocomplete')
        )
    },
```

And i got this error

[image]

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Introduced in the index.html page

```html
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"></script>
```

2. `new google.maps.places.Autocomplete()` change into `new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete()`;

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers))

Comment: i tried but it now show `Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

When you go to import the googlemaps scripts it is not said that the script has already been loaded.
The best thing is to put a global hook and then emit an event like maybe an eventHub.

Example of event hub https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-global-event-bus

```js
//your mapsPlugin.js
import eventHub from "./your-event-hub";

window.initAutocomplete = () => {
  eventHub.$emit("maps-loaded");
};
```

```js
mounted() {
    // mounted of your component
    eventHub.$on("maps-loaded", () => {
      // your stuff
    });
  },
```

Comment: what should i put into event-hub??

Comment: what you need to do with the google maps script, from the g-maps docs, only after the initAutocomplete (defined in the CDN) you can access the g-maps javascript API

Comment: in your case 
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            document.getElementById('autocomplete')
)

at least put a debugger statement end inspect if the gmaps script is correctly loaded